# Xcode Server CI Bot build failure - fails to launch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bots

After upgrading to Xcode7 the bots we have set up are failing to build with the following error:

```
2015-09-23 15:57:22.989 xcodebuild[23194:3737599] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -1712
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace *XXX* with scheme YYY.

Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -1712.)
```

The bots are set up to run against `iPads` with `IOS 9.0.`

Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: Some more information about the -1712 error : http://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-1712

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue with Xcode 7, but after restarting both the OS X server as well as the server machine where OS X server installed, the error got resolved. I guess its some launch issue problem with simulator.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. Just wondering if the IOS9 simulators take longer or need more memory to launch. Tried to launch the simulators manually by running Xcode on the CI server and they are really slow to launch.

Comment: I have same issue. My server is installed in macmini. quite slow.

Comment: Thanks, this did work for me on Yosemite Server with Xcode 7.1.